# PHP - force function evaluation?

Tags: php, function, metaprogramming

I'm using PHP 5.3, coming from JS and Python land, can't use call() because < PHP 5.4

So let's say I have a function generator, e.g. to log things in JS land:

```
function console($meth){
    return function() use($meth) {
        print "<script>console.".$meth.".apply(console,".json_encode(func_get_args()).")</script>";
    };
}
```

I want to dynamically evaluate this, like:

```
console($meth)($thing1,$thing2);
```

BUT

```
//console('log')('hello'); //syntax error!
```

sad tears! however, this works.

```
$func = console('log');
$func('hello');
```

WHY IS THIS THE CASE?  WHYWHYWHY?

Also, how can I force `console('log')` to evaluate without using `eval` or assigning to a variable?

Comment: 5.3 doesn't support function dereferencing.

Comment: It's just a limitation in the PHP parser, it doesn't allow you use a function call where a function name is expected. Prior to 5.4 you also can't use a function call as an array, e.g. `func(arg)[1]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This will work starting at PHP 5.3:

```
function console($a) {
    return function($b, $c) {
        echo $b, $c;
    };
}

$f = console("a");
$f("b", "c");
```

---

If you need to chain the call, this will work for all PHP 5 versions:

```
class Foo {

    public function call($b, $c) {
        echo $b, $c;
    }
}

function console($a) {
    return new Foo();
}

$f = console("a")->call("b", "c");
```

---

I would suggest to start learning PHP in a recent version. The PHP developers have added a lot of cool things in 5.4 and subsequent versions.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck in 5.3 land until the CTO decides it's safe to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

another way of solving that would be as follows:

```
    class App_Console {
        private static $methods = array(
            'log',
            'info',
            'warn',
            'dir',
            'time',
            'timeEnd',
            'trace',
            'error',
            'assert'
        );
        function __call($name,$args){
            if(in_array($name,self::$methods)){
                printf("<script>console.$name.apply(console,%s)</script>\n",json_encode($args));
            }
        }
    }
```